# Arbitrage bots are way too risky

Tags: flash-loans, flashbots

All I hear from forums is that the only way I can profit with a flash loan is I create my own arbitrage bot and I fund $800-$1600 worth of Ethereum upfront to cover for gas fees.

I've never made that much money in my life, and even if I had like $3200, this would still be really risky.

Again. EIGHT HUNDRED TO SIXTEEN HUNDRED DOLLARS WORTH OF ETHEREUM.

I'm not sure if I can just spend much less in BSC or Polygon.